# perlbrew ignoring minor version upgrade

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I am using perlbrew (`App::perlbrew/0.67`) on OS X 10.9

If I list the current installed Perl versions I get

```
$ perlbrew list
* perl-5.18.1 (5.18.2)
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2
```

So it seems that I have version 5.18.2 installed but listed as 5.18.1 (with the correct number in brackets)

```
$ perlbrew available
perl-5.19.11
perl-5.18.2
perl-5.16.3
...
```

`perlbrew available` is listing 5.18.2 (with 2). Is this normal or do I have a broken installation? Why does `list` show two versions (`--help` and the manual on CPAN do not show any hint).

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of perl installed, it's not that uncommon. Check all your include paths and see if any of them lead to different versions

Comment: @Analog But should `list` not show them?

Comment: Looks to me like you did a `perlbrew install` of 5.18.1 and then did a `perlbrew upgrade-perl` to that install when 5.18.2 was current.  Don't be concerned about `perlbrew available`, it's just listing what's sitting on the server for convenient download...

Comment: @ikegami I get it now. It's the name and the version in parenthesis. I installed 5.18.1 and named it 5.18.1 and then updated it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perl-5.18.1` is just an arbitrary name. You sure picked a weird one for an install of 5.18.2!

This is my list on one machine:

```
  5.8.9                  # 5.8.9
  5.8.9d                 # Debugging build of 5.8.9
  5.14.2                 # 5.14.2
  feed_fetcher (5.14.2)  # Used by specific project
  5.16.3t                # Threaded build of 5.16.3
* 5.18.0t                # Threaded build of 5.18.0
  latest (5.18.0)        # An (outdated) alias
```

Unfortunately, you can't fix this by simply renaming the directory. You can do `perlbrew install 5.18.2` to install 5.18.2 as `5.18.2`, make sure it works, then delete `$PERLBREW_ROOT/perls/5.18.1`.

---

If you plan on upgrading a build using `upgrade-perl`, create it as follows:

```
perlbrew install --as 5.18 5.18.0
```

You'd switch to that install using

```
perlbrew use 5.18        # This shell only
perlbrew switch 5.18     # Switch default
```

That way, the name will still make sense after you issue `perlbrew upgrade-perl`.